# Enroute time at distance given starting and ending time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, time

Overall distance: 1200 meters.
Time at 400 meters: 24.12 sec.
Time at 800 meters: 46.73 sec (24.12 + 22.61).
Time at 1200 meters: 69.69 sec (24.12 +22.61 + 22.96).

There is acceleration between 400m and 800 meters and deceleration between 800m and 1200m.

Is it possible to calculate the time at 1000 meters?

Not a homework question.

Comment: "Is it possible to calculate the time at 1000 meters?" - only if you make some assumption about the shape of the deceleration curve between 800m and 1200m.

Comment: what type of assumption might that be?